# Making a non uniform signal into uniform

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have 2 measurments, `t` and `Y`. `t` goes like `0.008145:1158.527`non uniformly, my `t` and `Y` are `<11000x1> double`

I want to make `t` equidistant or uniform and it doesn't matter if i lose in between few values, but I want the coressponding values in `Y`

Comment: Have a look at [interp1](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html?refresh=true)

Answer (score 1):

```
t_new = linespace (0.008145,1158.527,11000) ;
y_new = interp1 (t,y,t_new) ;
```